# How to order & count a dataframe by three variables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe, dftime, with a lot of variables, but a snapshot of the data looks like this:

```
| gene  | country | case_month | case_year |
| ----- | ------- | ---------- | --------- |
| gene1 | Senegal | February   | 2020      |
| gene2 | Botswana| January    | 2021      |
| gene3 | Congo   | March      | 2021      |
| gene4 | Guinea  | September  | 2020      |
```

Here's something reproducible:

```
structure(list(gene = c("gene1", "gene2", 
"gene3", "gene4", "gene5", 
"gene6"), date = structure(c(18319, 18328, 
18320, 18323, 18325, 18324), class = "Date"), country = c("Nigeria", 
"South Africa", "Senegal", "Senegal", "Senegal", "Senegal"), 
    case_month = c("February", "March", "February", "March", 
    "March", "March"), case_year = c("2020", "2020", "2020", 
    "2020", "2020", "2020")), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

I left in the date variable in case it's helpful! I took out case_month and case_year from date.

There are 38 countries overall, all 12 months are represented, and the only two years are 2020 and 2021. I'm trying to sort this data so that I can get the number of genes in Senegal during January 2020, Senegal in February 2020, etc. so that I get a count, n, of all the genes in each country during each month for each of the two years. I'm hoping for an output like this:

```
| country | case_month | case_year | n |
| ------- | ---------- | --------- |---|
| Senegal | January    | 2020      | 4 |
| Senegal | February   | 2020      | 6 |
| Senegal | March      | 2020      | 5 |
| Botswana| January    | 2021      | 1 |
| Congo   | March      | 2021      | 2 |
```

And so on...

The goal is that I can use this count to generate a stacked bar graph like this, with n being the new variable of the count:

```
dftime_stacked <- ggplot(dftime_ord, aes(fill=country, y= n, x=case_month)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")

dftime_stacked + facet_wrap(~ case_year)
```

I've tried to sort the data using dplyr, using mutate:

```
dftime_ord <- mutate(dftime, country = reorder(country, -n, sum),
                     case_month = reorder(case_month, -n, sum))
```

However this throws two errors — the first with -n, which says:

```
Error in -n : invalid argument to unary operator
```

The second when I take it out, because sorting by largest to smallest isn't the most crucial in this case because my countries are in alphabetical order anyway:

```
Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

All my variables are characters. Is there a reason it is unable to sort them in this way in dplyr? Any ideas why the error is being thrown like this? Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: Please share a sample of your data frame with ```dput()```. It will make things easier for others to help you.

Comment: What/Where is `n` in your data ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Shibaprasadb. I'll update!

Comment: @Ronak, so sorry for the confusion — I'm hoping n will be the new "count" variable, so that for example, n = 3 if there are 3 genes from Senegal in Feb of 2020.

Comment: @bergdoktor can you try to apply my solution to your data ? I updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can manipulate the orders via a `data.table` solution;

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(' gene  | country | case_month | case_year 
 gene1 | Senegal | February   | 2020      
 gene2 | Botswana| January    | 2021      
 gene3 | Congo   | March      | 2021      
 gene4 | Guinea  | September  | 2020      '),sep='|',header=T)

library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df <- df[,.(n=.N),by=c('country','case_year','case_month')]

setorderv(df,c('country','case_month'),c(-1,-1))
```

**output;**

```
  country     case_year case_month         n
  <fct>           <dbl> <fct>          <int>
1 " Senegal "      2020 " February   "     1
2 " Guinea  "      2020 " September  "     1
3 " Congo   "      2021 " March      "     1
4 " Botswana"      2021 " January    "     1
```

Comment: Thanks Samet, but I'm trying to count instances, sorry if this was super unclear. So the output should be: Senegal, February 2020, count = 1; and so on, if this makes more sense? I have over 27,000 genes so really it would be finding like 300 instances and so on

Comment: @bergdoktor I updated my answer a bit, can you check it out again ?

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help, @samet. This nearly got me there, but the output I got ended up counting all the sequences for each country, without distinguishing by case_month or case_year. I'm so sorry for initially posting something confusing — I updated the post with reproducible code and a sample output! I hope maybe this is helpful? Thanks again so much for this try

Comment: @bergdoktor no worries, I did the last touch. it will work :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for this ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(country, case_month, case_year) %>%
  mutate(country = reorder(country, -n, sum)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=country, y= n, x=case_month)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: this is what I'm looking for! But when I try to run this, I get: Error in count(., country, case_month, case_year) : 
  unused argument (case_year)

Comment: You might have `plyr` loaded. Try using `dplyr::count`.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, still trying this same error. Do you think it might be worth combing case_month and case_year into one variable and placing that onto the x axis? I initially wanted to separate them using facet_wrap, but maybe this is contributing to the error?

Comment: No, it should not matter. I don't get any such error on the sample that you have shared. Can you restart R and try again. If you are using `dplyr::count` instead of only `count` it should not give you atleast the same error.

Comment: apologies, turns out you were correct, but I'm still throwing an error: "Error in UseMethod("tally") : 
  no applicable method for 'tally' applied to an object of class "c('dtplyr_step_group', 'dtplyr_step')" So terribly sorry... thanks so much for all of your help so far, I really appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: Are you getting the data from a database? You may need to change it's class to dataframe or tibble object before using the above answer.

Comment: Originally yes, but I imported and cleaned up the original df in R — just confirmed it is a data.frame object!

Comment: That's strange. The error message suggests it is of type c('dtplyr_step_group', 'dtplyr_step'). What does `class(df)` return?

Comment: it returns  "data.table" "data.frame"!